# How to add an ADBannerView together with a UITableView in a UITabbar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, adbannerview

I'm a little bit confused about view-hierarchies when they meet ADBannerViews.
I want to insert iAd-Banners programmatically into an existing app, but I don't know where to start. I did read apples documentation and watched a really good WWDC-video, but I still have difficulties to understand how I can use this informations to bring ads in a propper way into my app.

**Here is the architecture of my app:**

At the bottom there is the window.
The rootViewController of that window is a UINavigationController.
The first viewController in the navigationControllers stack is a UITabBarController.
This tabBarController holds five simmilar UITableViews.
Tabbing on one of the tableCells of one of this tableViews pushes a new viewcontroller onto the navigationControllers stack.
This new viewController is again a UITabBarController, but this one has just four tabs, and the four Viewcontrollers in this tabBarControllers array are:

- two different UITableViewControllers
- two different simple UIViewControllers, one with just a single picture, the other with many nested views.

I want to insert an ADBannerView at the bottom of each of this four children of the second tabBarController in the navigationControllers stack. And I am not shure how to to this.

My problem is: I do not understand what will happen when the user tabs onto the ad. I know, that the ad's code will push a new view over my app, but I do not understand how. Will the new view be part of the stack of my navigationController (I don't think so)? Or will the new view be a new subview of one of the tabBarControllers views?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any proof, but my guess is that when the user taps on the banner, the ADBannerView code will push a new subview onto the view of the **root** view controller, because it needs to display full screen, on top of everything in your application. The root view controller is typically set in your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

p.s. off topic a bit but are you sure you want to change the number of tabs? The more conventional UI paradigm is the tabs stay constant at the bottom of the screen. In that case, you have a UITabBarController with several UINavigationControllers under it.